# How to integrate Excel-like Table Sorting And Filtering in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

[Excel-like Table Sorting And Filtering Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n12gC.jpg)
I am trying to use this type of filter in my vue table, Is there any vue plugin like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, you can get most of that with vuetify's data table (I would assume quassar and some others offer similiar things just less familiar).
Another more comprehensive option would be to integrate Hands On table into your app which offers the most features and options but you will need to pay for a license.
Of course you could implement this yourself but it seems to me that you don't need to reinvent the wheel and will save a lot of time using an existing framework.